# how do i call all data from 6 am to 8 am everyday

Tags: php, sql, localserver

this is my code:

```
<?php $date = date('d-m-y'); 
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"); //senarai pelajar awal 
include('config.php'); 
$sql="SELECT kedatangan.id,pelajar.nama,pelajar.tahun,kedatangan.masa FROM pelajar JOIN kedatangan ON pelajar.barcode=kedatangan.barcode WHERE masa BETWEEN '2017-01-01 06:00:00.000000' AND '2018-07-30 08:00:00.000000' "; 
$result = mysql_query($sql ,$conn)or die (mysql_error()); ?>
```

this code call all data from the begining of the date until the last date but it irrespective of time constraints

but i wanna call data **only from 6 am to 8 am everday **...i hope someone will help me

Comment: <?php
 
 $date = date('d-m-y');
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
 //senarai pelajar awal
 include('config.php');
 $sql="SELECT kedatangan.id,pelajar.nama,pelajar.tahun,kedatangan.masa FROM pelajar JOIN kedatangan ON pelajar.barcode=kedatangan.barcode
 WHERE `masa` BETWEEN '2017-01-01 06:00:00.000000' AND '2018-07-30 08:00:00.000000' ";
 $result = mysql_query($sql ,$conn)or die (mysql_error());
  
?>
 i already attech a picture but i does't show up

Comment: You have `...WHERE masa BETWEEN ...` and (perhaps) it should be `...WHERE kedatangan.masa BETWEEN ...`. You are not showing the complete structure of your tables and hence it is only possible to guess. By the way, I personally prefer the construct `.... WHERE X >= <Start of range> AND X < <End of range>...`. It is clearer for me and makes no performance difference.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the SQL query first? This might neither be a problem with PHP nor with any local server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select entries in between given time independent of dates, [CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function in mysql can make the help. The following query should work in this case.

```
SELECT kedatangan.id, pelajar.nama, pelajar.tahun, kedatangan.masa FROM pelajar JOIN kedatangan ON pelajar.barcode = kedatangan.barcode WHERE CAST(masa AS time) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '08:00:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `DATEPART`.
The following query should work in this case

```
SELECT kedatangan.id, pelajar.nama, pelajar.tahun, kedatangan.masa FROM pelajar 
JOIN kedatangan ON pelajar.barcode = kedatangan.barcode 
WHERE DATEPART(HH,masa) BETWEEN 6 AND 18
```